# Combine Columns to single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tuple that contains Column names that are dynamic `('Col1','Col2','Col3')`

I have a data frame where I need to create a calculated column (`FinalColumn`) by considering the values in the tuple.

In the above case:

```py
FinalColumn = df['Col1'] + ':' + df['Col2']+ ':' +  df['Col3']
```

If the above tuple contains two values ('Col1','Col2'), then:

```py
FinalColumn = df['Col1'] + ':' + df['Col2']
```

Comment: What is question?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Assuming you have a tuple of numerical columns for that you want to get sum, try `df["FinalColumn"] = df[list(tuple_name)].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: They are Text Columns

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

`t=("col1","col2")`
`df['Final_column'] = df[list(t)].apply(':'.join, axis=1)`

[image]